# Inefficient SQL query with DATETIME calculations. How to optimize?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem comes from real environment where the `production_plan` table captures the order identification and other details in each row. Each row is updated when the product is started to be produced and after its production -- to capture UTC time of the events.

There is a separate table `temperatures` that collects several temperatures at the production line -- in regular intervals, independently on anything, stored with the UTC.

The goal is to extract the sequence of measured temperatures for production of each product. (Then the temeratures should be processed, the chart of the values is created and attached to the product item documentation for audit purposes.)

**Updated** after marc_s comment. The original question did not consider any indexes. The updated text considers the following. The original measurement mentioned in comments.

The tables and indexes were created the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE production_plan (
        order_id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
        production_line uniqueidentifier NULL,
        prod_start DATETIME NULL,
        prod_end DATETIME NULL
);

-- About 31 000 rows inserted, ordered by order_id.
...

-- Clusteded index on ind_order_id.
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ind_order_id
ON production_plan (order_id ASC);

-- Non-clustered indices on the other columns.
CREATE INDEX ind_times
ON production_plan (production_line ASC, prod_start ASC, prod_end ASC);

------------------------------------------------------

-- There is actually more temperatures for one time (i.e. more
-- sensors). The UTC is the real time of the row insertion, hence
-- the primary key.
CREATE TABLE temperatures (
        UTC datetime PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        production_line uniqueidentifier NULL,
        temperature_1 float NULL  
);

-- About 91 000 rows inserted ordered by UTC.
...

-- Clusteded index on UTC is created automatically 
-- because of the PRIMARY KEY. Indices on temperature(s)
-- do not make sense.

-- Non-clustered index for production_line
CREATE INDEX ind_pl
ON temperatures (production_line ASC);

-- The tables were created, records inserted, and the indices
-- created for less than 1 second (for the sample on my computer).
```

The idea is to join the tables firstly on `production_line` identification, and secondly so, that the temperature UTC time fits between the UTC times of start/end of production of the item:

```
-- About 45 000 rows in about 24 seconds when no indices were used.
-- The same took less than one second with the indices (for my data
-- and my computer).
SELECT pp.order_id,      -- not related to the problem 
       pp.prod_start,    -- UTC of the start of production
       pp.prod_end,      -- UTC of the end of production
       t.UTC,            -- UTC of the temperature measurement
       t.temperature_1   -- the measured temperature
  INTO result_table02
  FROM production_plan AS pp
       JOIN temperatures AS t
         ON pp.production_line = t.production_line
            AND t.UTC BETWEEN pp.prod_start
                          AND pp.prod_end
  ORDER BY t.UTC;
```

The time about 24 seconds was not acceptable. It is clear that indexes were neccessary. The same operation took less than 1 second (the time in the yellow line below the result tabs in the Microsoft SQL Management Studio).

However...

**The second problem remains**

Because the temperature measurement is not too frequent and because the places of measurement is a bit shifted in time from starting the production, the time correction must be done. In other words, two offsets must be added to the time-range boundaries. I have ended with the query like this:

```
-- About 46 000 rows in about 9 minutes without indices.
-- It took about the same also with indices 
-- (8:50 instead of 9:00 or so).
DECLARE @offset_start INT;
SET @offset_start = -60  -- one minute = one sample before

DECLARE @offset_end INT;
SET @offset_end = +60    -- one minute = one sample after

SELECT pp.order_id,      -- not related to the problem 
       pp.prod_start,    -- UTC of the start of production
       pp.prod_end,      -- UTC of the end of production
       t.UTC,            -- UTC of the temperature measurement
       t.temperature_1   -- the measured temperature
  INTO result_table03
  FROM production_plan AS pp
       JOIN temperatures AS t
         ON pp.production_line = t.production_line
            AND t.UTC BETWEEN DATEADD(second, @offset_start, pp.prod_start)
                          AND DATEADD(second, @offset_end, pp.prod_end)
  ORDER BY t.UTC;
```

With the `DATEADD()` calculation, it takes about 9 minutes -- almost independently on whether indexes were created or not.

Thinking more about how to solve the problem, it seems to me that the corrected time boundaries (the UTC's with added offsets) need their own indexes for the efficient processing. Creating a temporary table comes to my mind. Then the index can be created for its corrected columns. Using one more JOIN should help after that. Then the table can be dropped.

Is the basic idea with the temporary table correct? Is there any other technique to do that?

Thanks for your suggestions. I will update the time results after introduction of the indexes suggested by you. Please, explain the reasons for the expected improvement. I am beginner concerning hands-on experience when writing SQL solutions.

Comment: Can you tell us which rows are the primary key and the foreign keys in your two tables? Are the primary keys clustered indices? Are the foreign key columns indexed? Have you looked at the execution plans for those two queries (and can you possibly even post them here)??

Comment: @marc_s: The tables were extracted rather artificially from the originals. No keys and indices were defined in the case. I will add them based on suggestions, and I will updated the question after observing the results. Basically, `order_id` in production plan and `production_line` in both tables should be Foreign Keys. If *clustered* index is the one based on physical sequence of rows, then `UTC` in the temperatures table could be the Primary Key with clustered index. (I am a beginner, I hope I am not confusing things too much.) How to capture the execution plan?

Comment: It looks like both your queries can fetch multiple rows per order_id, if there are multiple temperature readings during that time.  Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes, more temperatures for one `order_id` is the wanted behaviour. Actually, it is the goal. The temperatures are to be collected, processed, and added as the chart for the product documentation (audit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following solution with the temporary table:

```
-- UTC range expanded by the offsets -- temporary table used.
-- (Much better -- less than one second.)

DECLARE @offset_start INT;
SET @offset_start = -60  -- one minute = one sample before

DECLARE @offset_end INT;
SET @offset_end = +60    -- one minute = one sample after

-- Temporary table with the production_plan UTC range expanded.
SELECT production_line,
       order_id,
       prod_start,
       prod_end,
       DATEADD(second, @offset_start, prod_start) AS start,
       DATEADD(second, @offset_end, prod_end) AS bend
  INTO #pp     
  FROM production_plan;

CREATE INDEX ind_UTC
  ON #pp (production_line ASC, start ASC, bend ASC);

SELECT order_id,
       prod_start,
       prod_end,
       UTC,
       temperature_1
  INTO result_table06
  FROM #pp JOIN temperatures AS t
             ON #pp.production_line = t.production_line
                AND UTC BETWEEN #pp.start AND #pp.bend
  ORDER BY UTC;

DROP TABLE #pp;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ind_UTC
  ON result_table06 (UTC ASC);
```

The result is ready in less than one second (compare to 9 minutes). But I would like to hear your criticism. One problem is how efficient it is going to be if the temperatures table grows to a large table.

Comment: IMHO everything is in order here, but then again [Salieri thought the same about his piece](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ciFTP_KRy4) ;-) I still believe that index on temperatures should contain `UTC` - perhaps with `temperature_1` [included](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) if table has more columns than you have shown here. Prefixing column names with table names is considered good practise because it eases one's inevitable return to older code. With all that said - you have excellent approach to problems. This being the most important thing here.

Comment: The `temperatures.UTC` is defined as primary key. This way it has its own clustered index. On the other hand, `temperature_x` is just collected and never used in conditions or joins. This way I see no reason to pay for the index.

Comment: This depends. [Covering index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964133%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (skip to the part where it is explained) can be used for data retrieval when table on which it is defined has more columns not used anywhere in a query. This is a reason to have `include` syntax in index creation. In this manner query optimizer might choose not to read from original table at all. Very handy for speeding up sums from very wide tables because query engine reads a lot fewer pages from disk.

Answer (score 2):

You can usually optimize queries by:

- picking a **good** clustering key on your tables - good being `narrow, unique, static, ever-increasing`. `INT IDENTITY` is a classic good key - GUID's are a horribly bad example (since they lead to excessive index fragmentation - read Kim Tripp's [GUIDs as Primary and/or clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) for lots more details)
- making sure all foreign key columns in the child tables are **indexed** so that JOINs and lookups are performed faster
- selecting as little columns as you really need (you seem to be doing this just fine)
- trying to *cover the query*, e.g. create indices on the tables involved that have all the necessary columns - either directly as index columns, or as *included* columns (SQL Server 2008 and onwards)
- possibly adding additional indices to speed up range queries, and/or help with sorting/ordering

Looking at your queries and table definitions:

- I don't seem to see any primary keys - add those!
- you would have to make sure to have foreign key indices on `pp.production_line` (assuming `t.production_line` is the primary key of the other table)
- you should see if you can find a good index to handle the range query on `t.UTC`
- you should check if it makes sense to create an index on `production_plan2` to contain all the columns (`order_id, pp.prod_start, pp.prod_end`)
- you should check if it makes sense to create an index on `temperatures2` to contain all the columns (`UTC, temperature_1`)

**Update:** you can capture the actual execution plan by enabling that option from the SSMS toolbar:

[image]

or from the menu under `Query > Include Actual Execution Plan`

Comment: Thanks for comments and the article on GUID as primary keys. Unfortunately, the design of the application is older and I have no influence here. But I will pass the information to the one who may be interested. The `t.production_line` cannot be a primary key for the temperatures. The `production_line` is a kind of identification of one of the few physical machines.

Comment: I have updated the question. The indexes helped. However, the second problem remains. I did save the execution plan. When zipped, it takes about 4 KB. What there any usual place to upload files at StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1):

Things to try:

```
CREATE INDEX ind_pl
    ON temperatures (production_line ASC, UTC);
```

will provide covering index for join.

With non-equijoins apply (sql server 2005+) might be faster:

```
SELECT pp.order_id,      -- not related to the problem 
       pp.prod_start,    -- UTC of the start of production
       pp.prod_end,      -- UTC of the end of production
       t.UTC,            -- UTC of the temperature measurement
       t.temperature_1   -- the measured temperature
  INTO result_table02
  FROM production_plan AS pp
 CROSS APPLY
 (
   SELECT t1.utc, t1.temperature_1
     FROM temperatures AS t1
    WHERE t1.production_line = pp.production_line
      AND t1.UTC BETWEEN DATEADD(second, @offset_start, pp.prod_start)
                     AND DATEADD(second, @offset_end, pp.prod_end)
 ) t
 ORDER BY t.UTC;
```

If this doesn't work out, next option is to write stored procedure which will ensure that each table is read one time only, by declaring two cursors, one for pp and one for t, and advancing one side at a time while inserting matches into temporary table. This technique might be very complex because there is n:m relation. But, if above does not work for you, I'll be happy to give it a go.

Comment: It was a bit faster -- like 8:20 instead of 8:50 (minutes and seconds).

Comment: @pepr I was hoping for much better result. But, having lost any credibility, I will not say a word about your solution. You might consider adding [permanent calculated columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to `temperatures` and index them, to avoid temporary table altogether and not to worry about scalability. The only downside would be the need to specify offsets upfront, at the point of column definition.

Comment: The problem is that the offsets will be changed dynamically. The code is to be the body of a stored procedure. But your comment lead me to thinking more about it. Actually, *only the portions* of the `temperatures` table will be processed, and it will be done only once for the portion and never again. I have to rethink the consequences as the portions will be fairly short. P.S. You are funny about loosing the credibility. Stop kidding :)

Comment: Actually, the permanent calculated columns may be the way to go. I have to consult if the time offset will be changing for one machine.

Comment: Nikola, please, have a look a the temporary table solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11729350/1346705). I am beginner with SQL and it is likely the code contains beginner mistakes or that it can be improved.

Comment: Thanks, Nikola. I have found your comments the most inspiring.

Comment: Thanks @pepr, but I really haven't done anything to earn the bounty. You have done all the work yourself.

Comment: Don´t worry. You cannot eat the points, and cannot do it either. It is a game. There are more important things in the life. ;) The truth is that the game would be more fair if the bounty could be split. On the other hand, it is my decision.

Answer (score 1):

Computed columns can help you
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

```
ALTER TABLE production_plan ADD 
        offset_start int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF__production_plan__offset_start DEFAULT 0,
        offset_end int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF__production_plan__offset_end DEFAULT 0,
        prod_start_UTC as CAST(DATEADD(second,offset_start,prod_start) as DATETIME) PERSISTED  NOT NULL ,
        prod_end_UTC as CAST(DATEADD(second,offset_end,prod_end) as DATETIME) PERSISTED  NOT NULL

-- or just
--ALTER TABLE production_plan ADD 
--        prod_start_UTC as CAST(DATEADD(second,-60,prod_start) as DATETIME) PERSISTED  NOT NULL ,
--        prod_end_UTC as CAST(DATEADD(second,60,prod_end) as DATETIME) PERSISTED  NOT NULL

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[temperatures]') AND name = N'ind_pl')
    DROP INDEX [ind_pl] ON [dbo].[temperatures] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )

CREATE INDEX ind_times_UTC
ON production_plan (production_line ASC, prod_start_UTC ASC, prod_end_UTC ASC);

SELECT pp.order_id,      -- not related to the problem 
       pp.prod_start,    -- UTC of the start of production
       pp.prod_end,      -- UTC of the end of production
       t.UTC,            -- UTC of the temperature measurement
       t.temperature_1   -- the measured temperature
  INTO result_table05
  FROM production_plan AS pp
       JOIN temperatures AS t
         ON pp.production_line = t.production_line
            AND t.UTC BETWEEN pp.prod_start_UTC
                          AND pp.prod_end_UTC
ORDER BY t.UTC;
```

As well as recommendations made by marc_s

Comment: My +1, but it was already suggested by Nikola Markovinović. The problem is that the sensors just blindly measure the temperature each minute or so. But the machine works in batches, and production of one phase usually takes a different interval. This way the offsets are not fixed and must be calculated later, after the decision what UTC times belong to the batch. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is for your second problem.

I haven't checked the performance of this but you could try to skip the DATEADD function by replacing it with addition and subtraction of a constant float.

Like if you want to add a second you could use:

```
select getdate()+1.000/(24.00*60.00)
```

Or with a constant:

```
select getdate()+0.000694444
```

As you can see, adding 1 (one) will add exactly 1 day.
So this will not be exactly 60 seconds, but maybe that doesn't matter in this case?

Comment: I am a bit surprised that there is no strong type checking. Although, I understand that. I did precompute the float offsets (in seconds) like `SET @offset_startF = @offset_start/(24.00*3600.00)`. Then it took about 7 minutes against the earlier 9 minutes. My +1 for visible result, but I do not like that kind of mixing pears and apples. Still, it is--kind of--the same in principle (the time complexity is the same).

Comment: Сasting to float undocumented. You can get a problem depending on the version, or after the service pack